# No module named webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've just installed `Selenium` (I'm that new to it) for `Python` using

```
sudo -H pip install selenium
```

and at the following command

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
```

I get

> No module named webdriver

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you `import selenium` and check whether `selenium.__file__` points to correct folder that actually contains `webdriver`?

Comment: Tried the same import here and nothing seems wrong. Does just `import  selenium` also result in an error?

Comment: Why use H flag on sudo?

Comment: Was also wondering about the `sudo -H` flag. I never needed to use it.

Comment: I used the H flag because my Ubuntu system suggested it when I initially installed

Comment: `selenium.__file__` gives
`'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/__init__.pyc'` which looks right to me

Comment: I've just noticed if I type import selenium into the shell, it works okay; but when I run from a file I get the error.

Comment: The selenium package shows up when executing `pip list`?

Comment: yes, selenium package shows up when executing `pip list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your Python file is called

> selenium.py

Python interpreter at first tries to import files from directory you're in, so the solution is to rename the executed file and issue will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Check if site packages link is added in system environment variables;

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;

On windows start, type environment variables. Click on the "Edit the system environment variables" . Click -> Environment variables -> Under System Variables-> Scroll down to find "Path" -> Edit and add above path.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Answer (score -1):

first you need to import

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

then you can use other imports

Comment: This is not required. Why do you think so?

Comment: if I do not import above then my script will not know what webdriver is...thats why its important

Comment: My code works without first importing webdriver separately, which makes sense to me. When you are right, this would mean you always need to import each level of the package hierarchy.

Comment: without import at all  how you script understand what you are talking is, for selenium ...I am talking about python

Comment: @thebadguy, I'm afraid you don't get the point: Bouke wants to say that `from selenium.webdriver import Firefox` is totally the same as `from selenium import webdriver` + `from webdriver import Firefox`. That's why your answer obviously will not solve the issue

Comment: @Andersson... I was just saying if I do "from selenium.webdriver import Firefox" and then try to create instance of driver "driver = webdriver.FireFox()" then it gives me error unresolved reference name 'webdriver'. But if you do "from selenium import webdriver " then you no not need to import Firefox to create instance of webdriver

Comment: @thebadguy, If you do `from selenium.webdriver import Firefox` you should use it as `driver = Firefox()`! It's normal that you cannot call it as `webdriver.Firefox()` as you import `Firefox` class separately from `webdriver` module

Comment: Thanks for clarification